# How to get kubernetes Pod FQDN as container variable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am looking for a environment variable which can give me FQDN for a pod. Generally they are of format 1-2-3-4.default.pod.cluster.local. I want to use this for inter pod communication ( essentially forwarding a request to master node)

I used the following in deployment yaml but how do i convert my IP ( 1.2.3.4) to 1-2-3-4 ? And Is there a direct field for pod FQDN which i can refer like status.podIP

```
- name: MY_POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP  
- name: ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
  value: "$(MY_POD_IP).default.pod.cluster.local"
```

It created a variable like 1.2.3.4.default.pod.cluster.local but the correct FQDN is 1-2-3-4.default.pod.cluster.local

Any suggestions ?

Comment: There's no need to use hostnames for pod-to-pod communication in kubernetes; its networking model says that all pod IPs are addressable by all other pods in the cluster

Comment: @mdaniel Yes, but since we have a secured communication between pods, SSL certs validation is failing.

Answer (score 0):

For SSL certs validation you might want to check cert manager for your use case or sign certs with wild cards. That ways you will not face this issue.
For your exact issue, if you are using helm, you can use replace function in [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#replace).

Comment: If i don't use the FQDN, then it will create endpoint using https://1.2.3.4:444/ endpoint. Can we create SSL certs for IP address ? I guess not

Comment: not for IP address but FQDN that follow x-x-x-x.<namespace>.cluster.local. That's where cert manager or helm can solve your problem.

Comment: Since MY_POD_IP is a env variable which is not coming from helm. I am not sure if helm will be able to do it ? Is there an example for same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I provided link https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#replace, can you try on your side.

Comment: @SunilS You can for sure create SAN records for IP addresses: [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl#generating-certificate-signing-request-and-private-key) is a short example of doing so

Comment: @mdaniel these IP addresses are dynamically allocated by kube-system. There is no way for me to those IPs in advance. thats why i was looking for FQDN

Comment: And you presume your FQDN, _of the Pod's IP that is dynamically allocated_, is going to be fixed? I thought you had an `initContainer:` that was generating certs for you, but if you're asking "how can my Pod have a fixed IP that I can generate a cert for" that's not how kubernetes thinks of networking

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a direct field for pod FQDN which i can refer like status.podIP

All pod resource fields are described in [k8s api spec reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#pod-v1-core). I don't see anything that could be helpful to you. You can check it yourself.

---

> Any suggestions ?

If what you want is a static FQDN per pod, you can use StatefulSet with so called [stable network id](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id):

> Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the
> StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod. The pattern for the
> constructed hostname is $(statefulset name)-$(ordinal). The example
> above will create three Pods named web-0,web-1,web-2. A StatefulSet
> can use a Headless Service to control the domain of its Pods. The
> domain managed by this Service takes the form: $(service
> name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local, where "cluster.local" is the
> cluster domain. As each Pod is created, it gets a matching DNS
> subdomain, taking the form: $(podname).$(governing service domain),
> where the governing service is defined by the serviceName field on the
> StatefulSet.

So you can access the pod ([example in docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components)) with it's name, e.g.: `web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local`.

But note that Statefulset has some [limitations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations), so I recommend to get familiar with them before you decide to use it.

There is really no other way to do it, that I know of.

Additinally, you might want to check k8s docs about [k8s Cluster Networking model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/). Maybe you need to redefine the problem and solve it differently. It would have been much easier if you started with an actual problem you are trying to solve, and not with a solution.

Comment: Yes, we don't want stateful stateful set. We had already explored it. Regarding problem statement, let me try rewriting it.